# Field error , trying to reference custom user model

Tags: django

Got no idea what's going on here. First time using a custom user model so I'm having trouble referencing the user object in views. I know I need to use 'get_user_model' , but I'm not sure how to implement it. I tried doing a couple things but I'm still stuck.

**error**

```
FieldError at /mingle/
Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: date_joined, description, email, given_vote, id, is_active, is_admin, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, logentry, matches, password, photo, username, uservote
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/mingle/
Django Version: 2.2.3
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value:    
Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: date_joined, description, email, given_vote, id, is_active, is_admin, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, logentry, matches, password, photo, username, uservote
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py in names_to_path, line 1420
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['/Users/papichulo/Documents/DatingApp',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/papichulo/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 3 Apr 2020 23:46:27 +0000
```

Error at description = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user).description

**views.py, part that's giving me an error **

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from dating_app.forms import RegistrationForm,ProfileUpdateForm
from .models import Profile

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import os
from django.core import serializers
import json

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


def mingle(request):

try:
    user = (Profile.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id).exclude(uservote__voter=request.user).order_by('?')[0])
except IndexError:
    user = None
print(User.username)
try:
    description = models.Profile.objects.get(user=request.user).description
except models.Profile.DoesNotExist:
    create = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user = request.user)
    return redirect('profile')

match = models.Profile.objects.get(user=request.user).matches.all()
context = dict(user = user, match = match)  
return render(request, 'dating_app/mingle.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,BaseUserManager, User
from dating_project import settings



class ProfileManager(BaseUserManager):



    def create_user(self, username, email,description,photo, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("You must creat an email")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("You must create a username!")
        if not description:
            raise ValueError("You must write a description")
        if not photo:
            raise ValueError("You must upload a photo")

        user = self.model(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                username = username, 
                description= description,
                photo= photo,

            )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user 


    def create_superuser(self, username, email,description,photo, password):
        user = self.create_user(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                password=password,
                username=username,
                description=description,
                photo=photo,

            )

        user.is_admin=True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user




class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):

    email                       = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email")
    username                    = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined                 = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login                  = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active                   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #what I added
    description                 = models.TextField()
    photo                       = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photo',blank=False, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
    matches                     = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='+', blank=True)



    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['description','photo','email']


    objects = ProfileManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin


    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True



class UserVote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    voter = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='given_vote', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'voter'))
```

Comment: Use `Profile` instead of `models.Profile`. You have not imported "models"

Comment: @lain Shelvington.   I tried that, not working. Now I get.       "Exception Value: 
module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'Profile' "    after importing models

Comment: Can you post the traceback?

Comment: @IainShelvington Just did

Comment: Are you still using `models.Profile` somewhere? Can you post the traceback from the console not the debug response

Comment: @IainShelvington Sorry, just did it. I'm getting it elsewhere now

Comment: @IainShelvington wait I fixed that, but now I'm getting a field error  'Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: date_joined, description, email, given_vote, id, is_active, is_admin, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, logentry, matches, password, photo, username, uservote'

Comment: Profile doesn’t have a field named “user” so you can’t filter by it. If you’ve set Proflie to be your user model then you can just use request.user

Comment: @IainShelvington That worked, but now, on the same line, it says 'Profile' object is no itterable